# Coded UI Test .net frameworks supported

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am trying to use some of Microsoft coded UI test dlls in my program. I am using .Net 3.5 framework.

My question is;
Is it possible to use `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting` with .net 3.5 in VS 2010.

When I tried to add that an error displayed says `The type or namespace name 'VisualStudio' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is -The `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting` dll requires .NET 4.0 and up. You *can't* make it work with 3.5.

The easiest way to see this is to create a new 3.5 application and manually try to add the dll.
It's located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies` . Any attempt to add it as a reference will result in a Visual Studio warning that it *requires a later version of .Net framework*.

Also, notice that if you open the DLL in Reflector or [IL Spy](http://ilspy.net/) you'll see that the `TargetFramework` is 4.0